# Associating Knowledge articles with categories using REST API

Tags: rest-api, knowledge

The SOAP API suggests that articles can be associated with categories using [Article Type__DataCategorySelection](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_articletype__datacategoryselection.htm). I can't find information about using the REST API to do this and I've had no luck using `sobjects/MongoDB_Article__DataCategorySelection`. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to attach categories to article via REST API using the following endoint :

```
/services/data/vX.X/sobjects/TYPE__DataCategorySelection
```

version of the API as well as TYPE must be specified depend on your needs.

HTTP POST method
Body properties :

- dataCategoryName
- DataCategoryGroupName
- parentId (this is the article ID)

Don't know why there is still nothing explicit in Salesforce API doc
hope this will be helpfull